# Can we return an array of `AccountID` in NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol

Suppose I have a struct

```
pub struct Test {
    pub participant: Set<AccountId>
}
```

And I created a new account and inserted to participant using the `insert` function, I can get `len` of participant using `len()` method.
How can I get the address?

```
pub fn get_address(&self) -> Vec<AccountId> {
    self.participient.contains() // can't get data
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
self.participant.to_vec()
```

Comment: Thanks, How to do indexing or get specific value from array ?  EX:  `self.addr = self.participant[1];`  where `pub addr : AccountId`

Comment: You cannot index into a hashset, but if the type of `participant` is `Vec<AccountId>`, then you can do `self.addr = self.participant[1].clone()`.

Comment: Okay, but now with `Set` i can directly `insert` value to Set(`self.participant.insert(&owner_id)`), but with `Vec<AccountID>` `insert` method is not appending the value(ex: self.participant.insert(1, owner_id) ) so then I tried `push` (`self.participant.push(owner_id)`), but that also not happening. 
Which method is I need to prefer

Comment: push should work. However it takes a reference so it should be like `self.participants.push(&owner_id)`.